# julia plotly set plot figure size

Tags: plot, resize, size, julia, plotly

When I call the plot() function the resulting plot always has a fixed size when it opens in my browser. I have tried to pass a layout argument to the function in many forms but it always throws an "unhandled layout type" error.

Example code:

```
using Plots
plotly()
data = rand(10)
plot(data, layout = [:autosize=false, :width = 500, :height = 500])
plot(data, layout = [autosize=false, width = 500, height = 500])
plot(data, layout = ["autosize"=>false, "width" => 500, "height" => 500])
```

Is there anyone that knows how to pass this layout argument correctly?

Answer (score 9):

This can be done be specifying not a layout argument but the argument size:

```
plot(data, size = (width, height))
```

The layout argument I was referring to is used in the Plotly documentation but only applies when calling `Plotly.plot`, and not when you call `Plots.plot` with the Plotly backend selected. The `Plots.plot` call translates its own set of arguments to the selected backend.

For reference on the different usages:

- http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/attributes/
- https://plot.ly/julia/setting-graph-size/