# Make Julia outer plot dimensions the same in atom

Tags: julia, julia-plots

This is for viewing purposes. The actual scales are the same.

A short version of my question would be "Force grids to be square in plots".

As can be seen in the screenshot taken from the plot in Atom, while the axis are the same increments numerically, the grids are rectangular rather than square. I am not sure how to fix this. because the plot is wider than it is high, it skews the plot when I look at it.

[image]

if you do a quick estimate of the height of the Z and length of the X axis just using your fingers, you can tell that the X axis is considerably longer.

Comment: You might be looking for the [size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882995/julia-plotly-set-plot-figure-size) of your plot

Comment: or `xlim` and `ylim`

Comment: `xlim` and `ylim` are already in use, which is why the axis scales are exactly the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `ratio=1`, at least in Plots.jl:

```
julia> using Plots

julia> plot(rand(20,3), randn(20,3); ratio=1, 
             xticks=[-1,0,1], yticks=[-1,0,1], size=(600,300))
```

[image]